# Change in org-ctrl-c-ret?

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

I use spacemacs only for an org-mode todo file. I recently re-installed spacemacs and emacs and noticed a behavior change.

Let's say I have a file like:

```
* TODO Header
    - List item 1
    - List item 2
```

In inline mode, if I do Alt+Ret,Ret it used to be context specific. If I was on a header, then it would insert a new header at the same level; if I was on a list item line then it would insert a new list item. Now, no matter what line I am on it inserts a new header.

Comment: It still does what you expect for me (context specific insertions). What versions of emacs, org-mode and spacemaces are you using?

Comment: spacemacs: 0.200.13; 
emacs: 26.1; org-mode: 9.2.3

Comment: You mean `org-meta-ret`, not `org-ctrl-c-ret`, correct? Even so, I can't reproduce your issue with Org mode version 9.2.3 (release_9.2.3-367-gd79e80) freshly pulled from the git repo.

Comment: It looks like that is the problem - when I type  `M + Ret` the context menu shows that the `Ret` key will call `org-ctrl-c-ret`; when I use `M-x` and run `org-meta-ret` then it works as expected.

Comment: Not sure what context menu  you are talking about, but what does `C-h c M-RET` say? And is this in GUI emacs or emacs in a terminal?

Comment: Thanks for continued help. Nothing is returned when I do `C-h c M-RET`, but `C-h c M-RET RET` says that `M-RET RET runs the command org-ctrl-c-ret (found in spacemacs-org-mode-map-root-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in 'org.el'...`

Comment: So presumably `M-RET` has become a prefix somehow and lost its original meaning. You should try starting emacs with `-q` to avoid loading your init file (depending on how you load org, you might have to load a small init file to initialize org) and then try `M-RET` again. If that works, you have to dig through your init file to find where the errant setting for `M-RET` happens and fix it.

Comment: I believe that it is spacemacs that it doing it and that it's a spacemacs context menu that comes up for `M-RET`